# Indeed API XML are blocked after many request

Tags: xml, http

I have been using Indeed.com XML Feed API's for collecting job post for a test application. It seems that the API gets blocked for our server IP's and throws the following error.

> curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

The API documentation is been listed in the following link
https://ads.indeed.com/jobroll/xmlfeed

The API seems to work once the IP of the server is changed and thus the story continues after a specific amount request. The documentation has not specified any rate limit criteria so far I have learned from there site.

Answer (score 2):

FYI: indeed has discontinued their API.  All their documentation is still up but the links to get an API key get redirected to the hire page.  I called them and they said they have discontinued it.  Strange that they just can put that on their website.

Answer (score 1):

There is no specified rate limit but on their Affiliate Acceptable Use Policy page there are a raft of reasons that they can take the data away.

https://ads.indeed.com/jobroll/aaup.jsp

For example

> Program Elements may not be published on, or linked by Affiliate from, any website that: (a) is under construction, incomplete or non-functioning;

and

> Any use of Indeed's XML Application Programming Interface ('API') by Affiliate shall be solely in accordance with the guidelines stipulated by Indeed for use of the API which may include informational requirements, or restrictions on sizes of requests, frequency, and query complexity